# Using a COUNT value in an expression getting..does not include specified expression as part of an aggregate function

Tags: ms-access, count, aggregate-functions

I am trying to display a warning if a bike station gets to over 90% full or less than 10% full. When i run this query I get "you are trying to execute query that does not include the iif statment... as part of an aggregate function.

Bike_locations table - Bicycle_id and Locations_ID
Locations table - Locations_ID, No_of_Spaces, Location_Address

```
SELECT Locations.Location_Address, Count(Bike_Locations.Bicycle_ID) AS CountOfBicycle_ID,
IIf(((([CountOfBicycle_ID]/[LOCATIONS]![No_Of_Spaces])*100)>90),"This Station is nearly full.
Need to move some bicycles out of here",IIf(((([CountOfBicycle_ID]/[LOCATIONS]![No_Of_Spaces])*100)
<10),"This station is nearly empty. Need to move some bicycles here","")) AS Warnings
FROM Locations INNER JOIN Bike_Locations ON Locations.[LOCATIONS_ID] = Bike_Locations.[LOCATIONS_ID]
GROUP BY Locations.Location_Address;
```

Anyone got a scooby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a GROUP BY, you should have the exact same fields in both your SELECT and GROUP BY statements, except for the aggregate function that should only be specified in the SELECT

The aggregate function in your case is the COUNT(*)

The fields you aggregate on are:

- in the **SELECT** : *Location_Address* and *Warnings*
- in the **GROUP BY** : *Location_Address* only

The error message is telling you that you don't have the same in both statements.

2 solutions:

- Remove the *Warnings* from the SELECT statement
- Add the *Warnings* to the GROUP BY statement

Note that in MS Access SQL, you can't (unfortunately) use in the GROUP BY, the Aliases specified in the SELECT. So you have to copy over the whole field, which would be the long iif in your case

*Edit: better solution proposal:*

I would radically change your approach as you'll go no where with all those nested iff

Create the following Query and Name it (for instance) **Stations_Occupation**

```
SELECT L.Locations_ID AS ID, 
       L.Location_Address AS Addr, 
       L.No_of_Spaces AS TotSpace, 
       BL.cnt AS OccSpace, 
       ROUND((BL.cnt/L.No_of_Spaces*100),0) AS OccPourc
FROM Locations L
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT Locations_ID, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
    FROM Bike_Locations 
    GROUP BY LOCATIONS_ID
) AS BL ON L.Locations_ID = BL.Locations_ID
```

This query will probably be a lot helpfull in many parts of your application, and not only here, as it calculates the occupation % of each station

Some examples:

Get all stations with >90% occupation:

```
SELECT Addr
FROM Stations_Occupation
WHERE OccPourc > 90
```

Get all stations with <10% occupation:

```
SELECT Addr
FROM Stations_Occupation
WHERE OccPourc < 10
```

Get Occupation level of a specific station:

```
SELECT OccPourc
FROM Stations_Occupation
WHERE ID=specific_station_ID
```

Get number of bikes and max on a specific station:

```
SELECT OccSpace & "/" & TotSpace
FROM Stations_Occupation
WHERE ID=specific_station_ID
```

Comment: Still have same problem using that code. It is likely to do with the COUNT result being used in the iif statement. I tried nesting a SELECT but it printed each location loads of times with the warning appearing in a few of each locations resultset.

Comment: Ok. I had 45 minutes free during a train travel so I have spent it on a better solution proposal :) check my edited post and tell me if I fit your needs

Comment: Cheers Buck yer a genus. Thanks for the time

Comment: Just changed slightly the **Stations_Occupation** query: Changed to LEFT JOIN in order to also get the empty stations. Added a ROUND on the occupation %